# Is there a quick way to jump from a view in Interface Builder to its IBOutlet property in code?

Tags: ios, xcode

Right now, I am going through these steps to accomplish the same thing:

- right-click to find the name of the property
- open assistant editor
- use the 'Automatic' menu to find the relevant class
- look through the `.h` and `.m` files to find the property
- mouse-over the little circle next to the property to confirm that it is the right one

If anyone knows a quicker way it would be much appreciated.